# SQL Statement of SUM rows with conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have `user_id` = 23 that I want to query, I also have a table `work_log` include `project_id`, `user_id`, `log_hours` like this:

```
+----+------------+---------+-----------+
| id | project_id | user_id | log_hours |
+----+------------+---------+-----------+
| 1  |    23      |   23    |   2.5     |
| 1  |    3       |   23    |   3       |
| 1  |    23      |   23    |   1       |
| 1  |    24      |   23    |   3       |
| 1  |    24      |   23    |   1.5     |
| 1  |    23      |   23    |   0.5     |
+----+------------+---------+-----------+
```

But now I want sum all log_hours for each with result will have:

```
+------------+------------------+
| project_id | sum_of_log_hours |
+------------+------------------+
|     23     |       4          |
|     3      |       3          |
|     24     |       4.5        |
+------------+------------------+
```

How can I write SQL statement to have that result?

Comment: Have you tried to write it yourself?

Comment: Yes, I tried but it didn't work. The answer below is right for me

Comment: if the below answer is correct please mark it as answer. it can help to others.

Comment: The below answer is correct , you just need to remove the filtering `where user_id = '23'` to display all record with the sum of their log_hours.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Select project_id, sum(log_hours) as sum_log_hours
from work_log
where user_id = '23'
group by project_id
```

Answer (score 1):

To display all records with sum, just simply remove the `where` condition.

```
    SELECT project_id, sum(log_hours) AS sum_log_hours
    FROM work_log GROUP BY project_id
```